# Card carousel in Android with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I want to create composable function which can show elements(cards) like in the picture below. Is there any way to do it with LazyList or LazyColumn

I’ve tried VerticalPager from Google accompanist but I don’t know how to set them like on the picture[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking to make a carousel in Compose but I couldn't find, so I did it. The result is not perfect (height problem if too tall), but it can give an example.

I made an infinite LazyColumn and I change scale and zIndex for the content to make the carousel effect.

Here my function :

```
@Composable
fun Carousel(
  count: Int,
  parentModifier: Modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(540.dp),
  contentWidth: Dp,
  contentHeight: Dp,
  content: @Composable (modifier: Modifier, index: Int) -> Unit
) {
val listState = rememberLazyListState(Int.MAX_VALUE / 2)

BoxWithConstraints(
    modifier = parentModifier
) {
    val halfRowWidth = constraints.maxWidth / 2

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 10.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(-contentHeight / 2),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        items(
            count = Int.MAX_VALUE,
            itemContent = { globalIndex ->
                val scale by remember {
                    derivedStateOf {
                        val currentItem = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == globalIndex } ?: return@derivedStateOf 0.85f

                        (1f - minOf(1f, abs(currentItem.offset + (currentItem.size / 2) - halfRowWidth).toFloat() / halfRowWidth) * 0.25f)
                    }
                }

                content(
                    index = globalIndex % count,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(contentWidth)
                        .height(contentHeight)
                        .scale(scale)
                        .zIndex(scale * 10)
                )
            }
        )
    }
  }
}
```

And I call the function like this :

```
Carousel(
   count = list.size,
   contentWidth = maxWidth,
   contentHeight = 200.dp,
   content = { modifier, index ->
        MyComposableContent(
            item = list[index],
            modifier = modifier
        )
   }
)
```

[Carousel compose result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daDAF.gif)

Comment: Is it possible to limit the number of item on carousel but yet endless list? Let's say 3 items
1 center, 1 left and 1 right.

Comment: Yes, if you look at my second piece of code, you will see that I pass the list of items that I want to display. In your case you will pass 3 for "count" or "list.size", and for content you use your list with the returned index.

Comment: I got that.
Maybe i didn't explain it clearly. I ran your code but in animation i see 2 cards on top, 2 in bottom and 1 in center. I want 1 card on top, 1 in bottom and 1 in center. I'm trying to play with it how should i hide the other cards that are already half cut off.

Comment: Oh yeah I see. I don't find a simple solution. Maybe you can play with the size of parent and item to only display 3 items, or with index and the list of visible item (listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo). I don't have the solution sorry.